# Node.js SQLite get statements are not returning anything

Tags: node.js, express

im getting kinda frustrated because my node.js sqlite statement dont work for some reason as in it is not returning anything.

The code i am working with is:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./books.db');


function authenticate(){    
            db.get("SELECT Username FROM Authentication"), function(err,row) {
                console.log('test')
            }
    }
```

Now i have also tried to log the row itself but even the written 'test' doesnt log.
Note that i am using Node JS express

EDIT:
After fiddling a bit more with the code it seems that its not db.get() thats not executing but function(err,row). This is(according to the sqlite3 API) however the correct way to view results from query. Anyone know what i could be doing wrong with the callback?

Comment: Are you calling `authenticate()` further down in the code? Try logging `err` as well.

Comment: Yes i am but it seems the function is not being executed at all. Since whatever console.log is inside the funciton also does not get executed.

Comment: The problem is that `db.get()` never calls the callback that you're passing in. Can you use a query that's simpler? Or a different async call on `db`? You can also look at the source of `db.get()` to see what potentially takes a long time to execute.

Comment: If i do call the the callback function, as in i log either object err or row, nothing still gets logged. Now if the result were empty undefined would be logged but not even that is happening. It doesnt matter whether i call authenticate from another function or put db.get in another function. Nothing seems to happen either way.

Answer (score -1):

Alright it turned out to be a typo.

```
db.get("SELECT Username FROM Authentication"), function(err,row) {
                console.log('test')
            }
```

Should have been:

```
db.get("SELECT Username FROM Authentication", function(err,row) {
                console.log('test')
            })
```